# Tailwind textarea focus ring not showing on sides

Tags: css, tailwind-css

With Tailwind CSS, my textarea's focus shows fine on the top, but it is cut off on the sides of the element:

[image: Textarea focus ring not showing on sides]

These are the styles currently applied to the element:

```css
.dark .dark\:text-slate-200 {
  --tw-text-opacity: 1;
  color: rgb(226 232 240/var(--tw-text-opacity));
}
.dark .dark\:bg-gray-900 {
  --tw-bg-opacity: 1;
  background-color: rgb(17 24 39/var(--tw-bg-opacity));
}
.dark .dark\:border-gray-600 {
  --tw-border-opacity: 1;
  border-color: rgb(75 85 99/var(--tw-border-opacity));
}
.focus\:ring-theme-300:focus {
  --tw-ring-opacity: 1;
  --tw-ring-color: rgb(237 165 166/var(--tw-ring-opacity));
}
.focus\:outline-none:focus {
  outline: 2px solid transparent;
  outline-offset: 2px;
}
textarea:focus {
  --tw-ring-inset: var(--tw-empty, );
  --tw-ring-offset-width: 0px;
  --tw-ring-offset-color: #fff;
  --tw-ring-color: #2563eb;
  --tw-ring-offset-shadow: var(--tw-ring-inset) 0 0 0 var(--tw-ring-offset-width) var(--tw-ring-offset-color);
  --tw-ring-shadow: var(--tw-ring-inset) 0 0 0 calc(1px + var(--tw-ring-offset-width)) var(--tw-ring-color);
  border-color: #2563eb;
  box-shadow: var(--tw-ring-offset-shadow),var(--tw-ring-shadow),var(--tw-shadow);
  outline: 2px solid transparent;
  outline-offset: 2px;
}
```

I have tried adding `overflow-x: visible` to every element in the DOM tree down to the textarea, but that did not have any effect.

A demo is available [here](https://sandbox.svelte.saasfrontends.com/contact), it only works in dark mode so toggle the switch on the nav bar.

Comment: You are cutting it off in a div above your form with the following classes `relative max-w-xl mx-auto py-12 sm:py-6 w-full overflow-hidden`. The overflow-hidden coupled with the fact that there is no interior spacing means that your box-shadow (ring) will always be cut off. You can add some x padding to this element, or to the form, or anywhere just to keep some space between the element's edges that has overflow-hidden.

Comment: Great answer @JHeth, adding 2px of padding to the element with that class solved it! Feel free to make your comment a formal answer so I can accept/upvote